# SkyBot IRC bot - Now playing command

Tags: python, bots, irc, shoutcast

I have an IRC bot based on SkyBot (https://github.com/rmmh/skybot), and I would like to make a command for it that checks a ShoutCast stream and send the output in the format (Current_Song - Artist - Station_Name) as a message to the channel.

Unfortunately, my Python is rusty. I'm trying to pick it back up after about 3 years of leaving it alone. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I see it would be:

- Access the site using urllib or urllib2
- Use beautifulsoup to get the class/id/tag then retrieve the contents
- Put the data in a string then send it to the channel with the sockets/irc library

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for that.
I've been able to get it to output the current song, but I'm still having issues getting the listener count. I'm getting: "StreamTitle='';StreamUrl='';"
when I run the command I created.